# Figure numbering in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, alignment

[image]

I have used the following code to generate the results as shown in the figure, but numbering text(a) appears at the middle of the image, not at the bottom like another numbering. please provide a way to correct it.

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\center 
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}

\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png}} &  \includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png} & 
\includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png} &
\includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png} \\ 
\textbf{(a)} & \textbf{(b)} & \textbf{(c)} & \textbf{(d)} & \textbf{(e)}\tabularnewline
&
\includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png} & 
\includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png} & 
\includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png} &
\includegraphics[width=0.10\textwidth]{4.png}\\
 & \textbf{(f)} & \textbf{(g)} & \textbf{(h)} & \textbf{(i)}\tabularnewline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Would you also like to be able to reference your subfigures using \label and \ref?

Comment: thanks, dear but referencing figure is not a problem. I just want the solution of image numbering.

Comment: Instead of the tabular, I'd recommend using 4 vertically centered minipages to align the images and their corresponding letters. The first minipage will contain image (a), the second minipage is for image (b) and (f),...

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should of course be 5 minipages.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three possible layout options using `minipages` as already suggested earlier:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(a)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(b)}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(f)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(c)}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(g)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(d)}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(h)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(e)}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(i)}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(a)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(b)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(c)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(d)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(e)}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(f)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(g)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(h)}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(i)}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(a)}
  \end{minipage}\enspace
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(b)}
  \end{minipage}\enspace
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(c)}
  \end{minipage}\enspace
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(d)}
  \end{minipage}\enspace
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(e)}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(f)}
  \end{minipage}\enspace
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(g)}
  \end{minipage}\enspace
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(h)}
  \end{minipage}\enspace 
  \begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}

    \textbf{(i)}
  \end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow my new congratulations for this answer and :-) I'am glad for your new 20k reputation. "Bravissimo".

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks again for your congratulations. I didn't expect I'd reach it that fast.